# Error while installing firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firebase as my database. I ran `npm install angularfire2 firebase --save` and got the the following error stack:

> - C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp>npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
> - grpc@1.9.0 install C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\grpc
> - node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined):  https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.9.0/node-v57-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.9.0 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
> - gyp ERR! configure error
> - gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
>     HON env variable.
> - gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mo
>     dules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
> - gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_mod
>     ules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
> - gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\grac
>     eful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
> - gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
> - gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
> - gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodej
>     s\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--f
>     allback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\Users\Batbrain\Desk
>     top\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binar
>     y\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--modu
>     le_path=C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\
>     \grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown"
> - gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\gr
>     pc
> - gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
> - gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
> - gyp ERR! not ok
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.e
>     xe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.j
>     s configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Batbr
>     ain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binar
>     y\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_pat
>     h=C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node
>     \extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
>     node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Batbrain\Deskt
>     op\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\uti
>     l\compile.js:83:29)
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/chi
>     ld_process.js:209:5)
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Batb
>     rain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static
>     _library"
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_m
>     odules\grpc
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
> - node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>     Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node
>     _modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
>      --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Angular5\GitHub\tra
>     velapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\gr
>     pc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Batbrain\Desktop\Ang
>     ular5\GitHub\travelapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win3
>     2-x64-unknown' (1)
>     npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fse
>     vents):
>     npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
>     1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
>     )
> - npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> - npm ERR! errno 1
> - npm ERR! grpc@1.9.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
> - npm ERR! Exit status 1
> - npm ERR!
> - npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.9.0 install script.
> - npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
>     ging output above.
> - npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>     npm ERR!     C:\Users\Batbrain\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-02-15T04_11_
>     21_993Z-debug.log

Here's my environment details :

- Angular CLI: 1.6.8
- Node: 8.9.4
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 5.2.4
- @angular/cdk: 5.2.0
- @angular/cli: 1.6.8
- @angular/material: 5.2.0
- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
- @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
- @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
- @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
- @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
- @schematics/angular: 0.1.17
- typescript: 2.5.3
- webpack: 3.10.0
- npm 5.6.0

Comment: Do you have `angular-cli` installed globally?

Comment: Yes, I have `angular-cli` installed globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnRjB.png)

Answer

Simply exit from your Anti-virus Software and Run it Again .
It worked for me

[After Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8ksB.png)